# Find the difference between strings for each two rows of pandas data.frame

Tags: python, string, pandas, difference

I am new in python, and I am struggling with this for some time. 
I have a file that looks like this:

```
    name   seq
1   a1     bbb
2   a2     bbc
3   b1     fff
4   b2     fff
5   c1     aaa
6   c2     acg
```

where name is the name of the string and seq is the string.
I would like a new column or a new data frame that indicates the number of differences between every two rows without overlap. For example, I want the number of differences between sequences for the name [a1-a2] then [b1-b2] and lastly between [c1-c2].

So I need something like this:

```
    name   seq   diff  
1   a1     bbb    NA   
2   a2     bbc    1
3   b1     fff    NA
4   b2     fff    0
5   c1     aaa    NA
6   c2     acg    2
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What did you try to solve it? Are it allways two rows starting with the same character?

Comment: Yes, they start with the same letter and the only difference between them is the numbers at the end.

Comment: are there always two sequences for each letter? @LDT

Comment: Yes, and they are sorted as it is indicated in the example

Comment: Hey @LDT I think you have three proper solutions two your problem. I would tend to recommend you to accept yatu's or anky's versions, as they are sparse / more efficient and also have increased flexibility (over mine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you want the [jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) of the pairs of strings. Here's one way using `groupby` and [`scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard.html#scipy.spatial.distance.jaccard):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import jaccard
g = df.groupby(df.name.str[0])

df['diff'] = [sim for _, seqs in g.seq for sim in 
              [float('nan'), jaccard(*map(list,seqs))]]
```

---

```
print(df)

  name  seq  diff
1   a1  bbb   NaN
2   a2  bbc   1.0
3   b1  fff   NaN
4   b2  fff   0.0
5   c1  aaa   NaN
6   c2  acg   2.0
```

Comment: Nice one ,TIL:  `jaccard` i immidiately thought of `Levenshtein` seeing this . :)

Comment: Ah great then :) mm sounds like an option too,  can't recall what the similarity measure exactly was though @anky

Comment: Upvoted both your answers, as I was deeply impressed by your knowledge of string distance meassures (?) and efficency in your code-snippets

Comment: Thank you so much yatu. I wanted to ask you. If the "name" in my data.frame were like this [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] instead of [a1,a2], [b1,b2] , [c1,c2] what would I have to change in your code?

Comment: Use then `df.groupby(df.index//2` @LDT

Answer (score 5):

Alternative with `Levenshtein` distance:

```
import Levenshtein
s = df['name'].str[0]
out = df.assign(Diff=s.drop_duplicates(keep='last').map(df.groupby(s)['seq']
                    .apply(lambda x: Levenshtein.distance(x.iloc[0],x.iloc[-1]))))
```

---

```
  name  seq  Diff
1   a1  bbb   NaN
2   a2  bbc   1.0
3   b1  fff   NaN
4   b2  fff   0.0
5   c1  aaa   NaN
6   c2  acg   2.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much anky. I wanted to ask you. If the "name" in my data.frame were like this [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] instead of [a1,a2], [b1,b2] , [c1,c2] what would I have to change in your code?

Comment: @LDT then change `s` to `s = df['name']` instead of `s = df['name'].str[0]`

Comment: thank you so much. You saved me @anky. Happy holidays. Thanks for replying to my question as well

Answer (score 2):

As a first step I recreated your data with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# Setup
data = {'name': {1: 'a1', 2: 'a2', 3: 'b1', 4: 'b2', 5: 'c1', 6: 'c2'}, 'seq': {1: 'bbb', 2: 'bbc', 3: 'fff', 4: 'fff', 5: 'aaa', 6: 'acg'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Solution**
You could try to iterate over the dataframe and compare the `seq` value of the last iteration with the current one. For the comparison of the two strings (stored in the `seq` columns of your dataframe) you can apply a simple list comprehension like in this function:

```
def diff_letters(a,b):
    return sum ( a[i] != b[i] for i in range(len(a)) )
```

**Iteration over the Dataframe rows**

```
diff = ['NA']

row_iterator = df.iterrows()
_, last = next(row_iterator)

# Iterate over the df get populate a list with result of the comparison
for i, row in row_iterator:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        diff.append(diff_letters(last['seq'],row['seq']))
    else:
        # for odd row numbers append NA value
        diff.append("NA")
    last = row
df['diff'] = diff
```

**Result looks like this**

```
  name  seq diff
1   a1  bbb   NA
2   a2  bbc    1
3   b1  fff   NA
4   b2  fff    0
5   c1  aaa   NA
6   c2  acg    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this one

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name':  ['a1', 'a2','b1','b2','c1','c2'],
    'seq': ['bbb', 'bbc','fff','fff','aaa','acg']
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['name','seq'])
diffCntr=0
df['diff'] = np.nan
i=0
while i < len(df)-1:
    diffCntr=np.nan
    item=df.at[i,'seq']
    df.at[i,'diff']=diffCntr
    diffCntr=0
    for j in df.at[i+1,'seq']:
        if item.find(j) < 0:
            diffCntr +=1
    df.at[i+1,'diff']=diffCntr
    i +=2    
df
```

The result is this:

```
    name seq    diff
0   a1   bbb    NaN
1   a2   bbc    1.0
2   b1   fff    NaN
3   b2   fff    0.0
4   c1   aaa    NaN
5   c2   acg    2.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much Rola. I wanted to ask you. If the "name" in my data.frame were like this [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] instead of [a1,a2], [b1,b2] , [c1,c2] what would I have to change in your code?

Comment: @LDT nothing to change in the code. you have only to change the data in your df to be 1,1,2,2,3,3 instead of a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2 . my code traces the df records and compares "seq" values in each two consequent rows regardless of the values inserted in "name" column.